# Post method with ajax and jquery in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to enter values ​​to my table "Categories" so as not to reload the page and keep the user always in sight, for this I want to use Ajax + Jquery, the exercise seems simple but it has me crazy, you enter category names in an input and you want to show a `<div>` for your confirmation (success) or failure (danger) depending on the case, something like that ....

[image: CrearCategoria]

The problem is that my Javascript code does not do anything, it is not even entering the Create method

I enclose my view create.html:

```
 <head>  
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

</head>
 <body>
                <div id="div-alerta">
                    <label id="mensaje-alerta"></label>
                </div>

                <hr />             
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.v_Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="txtNombre" />

                    </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">               
                        <input type="button" value="Crear" id="btnCrearCategoria" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
  </body>
  </html>

            @section Scripts {
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")

              <script>
                  $(function () {
                      $("#btnCrearCategoria").click(function () {

                          var url = "@Url.Action("Create", "Categorias")";
                          var nombre = $("#txtNombre").val();
                          var data = { v_Nombre: nombre };

                          $.post(url, data).done(function (data) {
                              if (data.Ok) {
                                  $("#div-alerta").removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert-success").slideDown(100);
                              }
                              else {
                                  $("div-alerta").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert-danger").slideDown(100);
                              }

                              $("#mensaje-alerta").html(data.Mensaje)
                          })
                      })
                  })
        </script>

            }
```

This is my object category.cs:

```
  public class Categoria
        {
            [Key]
            public int Kn_CodigoCategoria { get; set; }

            [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es obligatorio")]
            [MaxLength(40, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} debe tener un máximo de {0} caracteres")]
            [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
            [Index("Categoria_v_Nombre_Index", IsUnique = true)]
            [Display(Name = "Nombre Categoria")]
            public string v_Nombre { get; set; }
        }
```

and this is my create method that returns a Json:

```
       [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public JsonResult Create(Categoria categoria)
            {
                var resultado = new BaseRespuesta();

                try
                {
                       db.Categorias.Add(categoria);
                       db.SaveChanges();

                    resultado.Mensaje = "Categoria creada correctamente";
                    resultado.Ok = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    resultado.Mensaje = ex.Message;
                    resultado.Ok = false;
                }

                return Json(resultado);
       }
```

I occupy a class called BaseResponse to see messages of success or failure of my operation:

```
 public class BaseRespuesta
    {
        public bool Ok { get; set; }
        public string Mensaje { get; set; }
    }
```

My expected behavior: When entering a value in the text box, show me a div (success or failure) with the corresponding message

My behavior obtained: entering a value in the input does nothing

what am I doing wrong? I'm missing something in my code? it's the first time I work with Ajax calls ... should I load a partial view? any help for me?

Comment: First you are loading 2 copies of jquery. Your `@section Scripts {` code does not make sense because you do not appear to have a layout.

Comment: Open your browser console. Do you see any error messages there ?

Comment: What does it mean to have no design? @StephenMuecke

Comment: there are no errors in the debugger of my console @Shyju

Comment: @fytoahse, Sorry, but I do not understand you comment

Comment: you never understand me, but I can understand it ... I do not understand what you mean that my section script has no design @StephenMuecke

Comment: I never said your _section script has no design_ - I said you view does not have a layout (e.g. `@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml" }`), and your script is not within the `<html>` tags

Comment: he included the scripts in my Layout.cshtml too ... and also obviate the HTML tag in my question to save code @StephenMuecke

Comment: **My expected behavior: When entering a value in the text box, show me a div** The code you shared is trying to handle the click event on the button with id btnCrearCategoria. Put an alert/console.log inside that  event handler and debug

Comment: Show your REAL code!

Comment: by putting an alert with your preferences after the event click on throw function log () {
[native code]
} @Shyju

Comment: What are you alerting ? Also `console.log` is useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` as decoration of my JsonResult blocked my Javascript action, eliminating this decoration and leaving only `[HttpPost]` worked for me !!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this might be wrong:

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Create", "Categorias")";
```

To pass in the string `"Categorias"` to the action `"Create"`, it would be something like the following where you would create an 'anonymous' type. Maybe try:

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Create", new { categoria = "Categorias"})";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have double quotes that aren't being escaped:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#btnCrearCategoria").click(function () {

            **var url = "@Url.Action("Create", "Categorias")";**
            var nombre = $("#txtNombre").val();
            var data = {
                v_Nombre: nombre
            };

            $.post(url, data).done(function (data) {
                if (data.Ok) {
                    $("#div-alerta").removeClass("alert-danger").addClass("alert-success").slideDown(
                        100);
                } else {
                    $("div-alerta").removeClass("alert-success").addClass("alert-danger").slideDown(
                        100);
                }

                $("#mensaje-alerta").html(data.Mensaje)
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

You need to either escape them or use single quotes around the whole string:

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Create", "Categorias")';
```

or

```
var url = "@Url.Action(\"Create\", \"Categorias\")";
```

The second option can get tricky trying to manage all of the "\" backslashes so I would recommend the first option.

Comment: I have changed my double quotes to single quotes and it still does not work! I do not even enter my method!

Comment: There is no need to escape/change double quotes to single quotes. The double quotes inside the `Url.Action` method gets executed in server and browser gets a string value. So the output is going to be something like `var url = "someStringForUrl";`

Comment: @Shyju that's fair. Good catch.